# Why does EF create a new db instead of using the existing db?

Tags: entity-framework

I have an existing SQL Server Express database populated with data.

I created a new VS solution built around EF 5. I generated the EDMX from the existing database and verified the connection string in the `app.config` points to the database on `.\SQLEXPRESS`.

I created a project for my domain objects.

I added a `DbContext` generator. The domain objects are also generated.

Everything builds and the console application runs.

The problem, however, is a new database is created instead of using the existing database.

Why does EF create a new empty database instead of using the existing database I specified? And how do I fix it?

Here is the `DbContext` class:

```
public partial class ContactsEntities : DbContext
{
        public ContactsEntities()
            : base("name=ContactsEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AddressType> AddressTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PhoneType> PhoneTypes { get; set; }
}
```

And the entire `app.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ContactsEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/PeopleModel.csdl|res://*/PeopleModel.ssdl|res://*/PeopleModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(local)\sqlexpress;initial catalog=Contacts;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

And here is the PeopleContext scaffolded using the T4Scaffolding:

```
   public class PeopleContext : DbContext
    {
        // You can add custom code to this file. Changes will not be overwritten.
        // 
        // If you want Entity Framework to drop and regenerate your database
        // automatically whenever you change your model schema, add the following
        // code to the Application_Start method in your Global.asax file.
        // Note: this will destroy and re-create your database with every model change.
        // 
        // System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DataLayer.Models.PeopleContext>());

        public DbSet<Domain.Person> People { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: How does the generated DbContext derived class look like? Especially the constructor? Also, show your config.

Comment: From your edit it looks like you want it to use the Contacts database in your local sqlexpress database. What database does it use? You can also check what ((IObjectContextAdapter)DbContext).ObjectContext.Connection.ConnectionString returns - it will tell you what database it connects to.

Comment: I want it to use the Contacts db from .\SQLEXPRESS but it creates a new database named `DataLayer.Models.PeopleContext`. I have a class named `PeopleContext` in the `DataLayer.Models` namespace. It was created along with the `PersonRepository.cs` by the T4Scaffolding tool

Comment: The PeopleContext rather than the ContactsEntities is being used somewhere. You can either add a constructor to the PeopleContext that contains connection string name (i.e. `public PeopleContext() : base("name=ContactsEntities") {}`) or remove PeopleContext and use ContactsEntities in the places where you are now using PeopleContext